# Insert comma separator at fixed position in unix

Tags: string, csv

I have a csv file with the first few characters are in YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS format
e.g.

```
20150710-071458source,data1,data2,data3
20150710-091458source,data1,data2,data3
20150810-101458source,data1,data2,data3
20150910-103058source,data1,data2,data3
```

I want to split the first field into new columns for further processing. Expected result would be

```
2015,07,10,07,14,58,source,data1,data2,data3
2015,07,10,09,14,58,source,data1,data2,data3
2015,08,10,10,14,58,source,data1,data2,data3
2015,09,10,10,30,58,source,data1,data2,data3
```

How can I insert the commas in fixed position? Some people suggest using sed. But I could not find the exact parameters. Could somebody help on this using sed,awk,cut whatever? Thank you very much! ^_^

Comment: any attempts in awk,sed,perl or anything? Thank you very much! :(

Comment: Googled for many posts but still could not find clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `sed`, this will do it:

```
centos6:~-> echo 20150710-071458source,data1,data2,data3 | sed 's/.\{4,4\}/&,/;s/.\{7,7\}/&,/;s/-/,/;s/.\{13,13\}/&,/;s/.\{16,16\}/&,/;s/.\{19,19\}/&,/'
2015,07,10,07,14,58,source,data1,data2,data3
centos6:~->
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty either, but it works ...

```
cat test.file | awk '{print substr($1, 0, 8)","substr($1, 10, 2)","substr($1, 12, 2)","substr($1, 14, 2)","substr($1, 16)}';
```